# Change element background-image inside a v-for

Tags: vue.js

I have a `v-for` thats reading different `.md` files which have a image property in their front matter.

I am trying to change my div's `background-image` But it has to read that url taken from the files frontmatter.

this is the code:

```
<div v-for="item in projectsList" class="li" >
                    <div style="background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4f/c4/92/4fc49228a940e41435b3796c18fc2346.jpg)">
                        <a :href="item.path" class="li">
                            <span>{{ item.title }}</span>                       
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Now the issue** lies in changing the `style:"background-image: url(<URL>)` property.

I can access the image through `item.frontmatter.image`,

I read about [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuejs-access-v-for-variable-in-v-bind-style/873) so i tried to do an example and just for testing purposes tried to feed an image through the Data function, but to vue the Url is undefined so i need a different way of feeding a URL based image to the background.

```
:style:"{'background-image': url( imageURL )}"

data: function () {
            return {
                imageURL: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4f/c4/92/4fc49228a940e41435b3796c18fc2346.jpg' 

            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
<div v-for="item in projectsList" class="li" >
  <div :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${item.frontmatter.image})` }">
    <a :href="item.path" class="li">
      <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

No data function needed here I think.